# Linux one-to-many multiplexer

Tags: linux, pipe, linux-device-driver

I'm creating a simple device driver in Linux that should read some data, over serial, parse it, structure it and then stream it to any process that requires the data.

I thought the best way to achieve this is by broadcasting the data using pipes.

What's the best to pipe the output of process A into the input of N other processes, in Linux?

Thanks!

Comment: I hate to say this, but `dbus` may be the most appropriate thing to use...

Comment: Better would be to broadcast using a unix socket.

Comment: @tc. is probably right.  If it's a serial port, this isn't a performance-sensitive application.  The system already comes with a very featureful (if somewhat clunky) IPC system well-suited to publish/subscribe models like this.  There are clean wrapper APIs for D-Bus in almost all languages at this point.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I'm also experimenting creating a simple daemon as and use unix sockets as it might be the best approach for this specific problem. Let me check dbus as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I would make the driver write into a circular buffer in memory and have counterpart API to discover the address of the buffer and to read the data from the buffer into consumer's private memory. In my implementation slow consumer might not receive all data, but this can be solved by introducing a caching fast consume to be queueing large amount of data for slow consumers recovery.

Comment: Thanks! :) That's definitely an option. I'm thinking about implementing a simple daemon and I might use a similar approach internally.